# Vector is not a member of std with everything included

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, std

I'm getting a very strange error and something I've never experienced before, I'm trying to initialize a vector at declaration like so:

```
  vector <int> myVector (5,4,3,4);
```

It gives me an error saying that it cannot find a call matching that function, however, if I plug in only 2 numbers it doesn't give me an error.

Upon further investigation, even this piece of code throws that vector is not a member of std or that myVector is not a type when I try to call

```
myVector.push_back(4);
```

Now here is the code that gives me the vector is not a member of std, not matching function found, of that nature...

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

const std::vector<int> newvector;
std::newvector.push_back(5);

int main()
{
}
```

Error given: newvector in namespace std does not name a type

Comment: In addition to the answers below - Push_back is not a const method.  You're going to have trouble calling it on a const vector

Comment: Your vector object is called `newvector`, not `std::newvector`.

Comment: You have to call `push_back` inside a function. You can rig it so a global object's constructor calls it if you want.

Comment: ^Declaring the vector and calling push_back inside a function fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the final code example,

you can't have this statement outside a function body:

```
std::newvector.push_back(5);
```

Place it in `main`'s function body, *and* remove the `std::` prefix.

Also note that for this vector modification to be possible, the vector can't be `const`.

---

Initialization with round parentheses provides arguments to a constructor for the class. There must be a corresponding constructor. And there is no `std::vector` constructor that corresponds to the four arguments in

```
vector <int> myVector (5,4,3,4);
```

Instead do

```
vector <int> myVector = {5,4,3,4};
```

If your compiler supports this C++11 syntax, that is.

If not, then the C++03 way would be

```
static int const data[] = {5,4,3,4};
static int const n_items = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);

vector <int> myVector( data, data + n_items );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::newvector.push_back(5);
```

since `newvector` is a variable, it is not in namespace `std`.

For this case:

```
vector <int> myVector (5,4,3,4);
```

If you only use two values `(5,4)` in this case, it will create a vector with size 5 and each of the elements initialized to 4 (one form of vector construction). If you need to initialize a vector with a list of values, you may try uniform initialization since C++11 as follows:

```
std::vector <int> myVector{5,4,3,4};
```

Some example of `uniform initialization` can be found here: [uniform initialization and other C++11 features](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/)

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with this code.

1. `using std::vector;` brings a `vector` from namespace `std` but you have to use this as follows:

   ```
   std::vector<int> newvector;
   newvector.push_back(5);
   ```
2. You can notice that const dissapeared. This is because you want to change vector at last, so it cannot be `const`, it would be compile error to call a `push_back` on it otherwise.

Finally, this should be:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int main() {
  std::vector<int> newvector;
  newvector.push_back(5);
  std::vector<int> newvector;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second error, you cannot initialize a `vector` with its elements in the constructor, you must use its initializer list (C++11 only)

```
vector <int> myVector = {5,4,3,4};
```